# Sri Lanka paper map sheet key

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, sri-lanka

I have a list of river gauging station locations, with the coordinates given in a local system:

```
L/24(5.5*8.15)
O/13(3.5*0.15)
P/3(0.9*2.1)
M/17(13.5*1.6)
```

Presumably these coordinates are pointing to a particular sheet and then the location on that sheet.

Has anyone got some more information on using these coordinates, maybe some sort of key to the map sheets? Ideally I want to convert to something usable (maybe decimal degrees).

Comment: I thought the a*b values could be truncated coordinates, but they don't obviously fit the national grids listed in the EPSG registry. There could be some info in "Index to World Topographic Mapping" vol. 3 but the Esri library doesn't have a copy. Amazon lists a few expensive copies.